The type or namespace name 'Cinemachine' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
I'm encountering an issue with the Cinemachine package in Unity. I've installed Cinemachine in a new Unity 3D URP project through the Package Manager, but I keep getting the error:
Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Cinemachine' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Here's what I've done so far to troubleshoot:

Installed Cinemachine (in a new empty project)

Opened the Package Manager (Window -> Package Manager).
Ensured "Packages: Unity Registry" was selected.
Installed the latest version of Cinemachine.


Verified Installation:

Cinemachine is listed under Packages: In Project in the Package Manager.
The Cinemachine menu item appears under GameObject -> Cinemachine.


Test Script:

Created a new script named CinemachineTest.cs with the following content:
using UnityEngine;
using Cinemachine;

public class CinemachineTest : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log("Cinemachine namespace is available.");
    }
}


Attached the script to a GameObject in the scene.




Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!
Expected Result: The script should compile without errors, and running the scene should display "Cinemachine namespace is available." in the console.
Actual Result: The script fails to compile with the error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Cinemachine' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).
Troubleshooting Steps I've Tried:
Restarting Unity.
Reimporting all assets (Assets -> Reimport All).
Ensuring no other compile errors exist in the console.


Your IDE should have guided you to where the name space is.. its not Cinemachine, but Unity.Cinemachine

The namespaces have been changed from Cinemachine to Unity.Cinemachine.
https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.cinemachine@3.0/manual/CinemachineUpgradeFrom2.html
